# Error on starting Hbase 1.0.0

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have just installed Hbase through `brew install hbase`. Edited hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/Cellar/hbase/databases/hbase-${user.name}/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by region servers and into
    which HBase persists.  The URL should be 'fully-qualified'
    to include the filesystem scheme.  For example, to specify the
    HDFS directory '/hbase' where the HDFS instance's namenode is
    running at namenode.example.org on port 9000, set this value to:
    hdfs://namenode.example.org:9000/hbase.  By default HBase writes
    into /tmp.  Change this configuration else all data will be lost
    on machine restart.
    </description>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Exported JAVA_HOME and HBASE_HOME.
When i'm trying to start i m getting following exception:

```
Abhisheks-MacBook-Pro:bin abhishek$ start-hbase.sh 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.HBaseConfTool
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
starting master, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.0/logs/hbase-abhishek-master-Abhisheks-MacBook-Pro.local.out
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster
cat: /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.0/conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
cat: /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.0/conf/regionservers: No such file or directory
```

I have Hadoop2.6.0 and Hbase1.0.0. Though i'm seeing many people have already faced this problem but i cannot find the solution. What else needs to be done to start Hbase without any issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.0/libexec
it should be configured such that conf folder lies in HBASE_HOME directory.

Checking master-status:

**localhost:60010**

edit hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/Cellar/hbase/databases/hbase-${user.name}/hbase</value>
    <description>The directory shared by region servers and into
    which HBase persists.  The URL should be 'fully-qualified'
    to include the filesystem scheme.  For example, to specify the
    HDFS directory '/hbase' where the HDFS instance's namenode is
    running at namenode.example.org on port 9000, set this value to:
    hdfs://namenode.example.org:9000/hbase.  By default HBase writes
    into /tmp.  Change this configuration else all data will be lost
    on machine restart.
    </description>
 </property>
<property >
    <name>hbase.master.port</name>
    <value>60000</value>
    <description>The port the HBase Master should bind to.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master.info.port</name>
    <value>60010</value>
    <description>The port for the HBase Master web UI.
    Set to -1 if you do not want a UI instance run.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```